# In Tensorflow, I do not know why I trained a model, the training loss decreased, but seem like it is not trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Here is my code and result of the training.

```
batch_size = 100
epochs = 50
yale_history = yale_classifier.fit(x_train, y_train_oh,batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,validation_data=(x_train,y_train_oh))
```

```
Epoch 1/50
20/20 [==============================] - 32s 2s/step - loss: 3.9801 - accuracy: 0.2071 - val_loss: 3.6919 - val_accuracy: 0.0245
Epoch 2/50
20/20 [==============================] - 30s 2s/step - loss: 1.2557 - accuracy: 0.6847 - val_loss: 4.1914 - val_accuracy: 0.0245
Epoch 3/50
20/20 [==============================] - 30s 2s/step - loss: 0.4408 - accuracy: 0.8954 - val_loss: 4.6284 - val_accuracy: 0.0245
Epoch 4/50
20/20 [==============================] - 30s 2s/step - loss: 0.1822 - accuracy: 0.9592 - val_loss: 4.9481 - val_accuracy: 0.0398
Epoch 5/50
20/20 [==============================] - 30s 2s/step - loss: 0.1252 - accuracy: 0.9760 - val_loss: 5.3728 - val_accuracy: 0.0276
Epoch 6/50
20/20 [==============================] - 30s 2s/step - loss: 0.0927 - accuracy: 0.9816 - val_loss: 5.7009 - val_accuracy: 0.0260
Epoch 7/50
20/20 [==============================] - 30s 2s/step - loss: 0.0858 - accuracy: 0.9837 - val_loss: 6.0049 - val_accuracy: 0.0260
Epoch 8/50
20/20 [==============================] - 30s 2s/step - loss: 0.0646 - accuracy: 0.9867 - val_loss: 6.3786 - val_accuracy: 0.0260
Epoch 9/50
20/20 [==============================] - 30s 2s/step - loss: 0.0489 - accuracy: 0.9898 - val_loss: 6.5156 - val_accuracy: 0.0260
```

You can see that I also used the training data as the validation data. This is weird that the training loss is not the same as the validation loss. Further, when I evaluated it, seem like my model was not trained at all as follow.

```
yale_classifier.evaluate(x_train, y_train_oh)
```

```
62/62 [==============================] - 6s 96ms/step - loss: 7.1123 - accuracy: 0.0260
[7.112329483032227, 0.026020407676696777]
```

Do you have any recommened to solve this problem ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: your model is training correctly. The validation loss and accuracy is not improving so I suspect you have incorrect validation data